# How to get grooves/ridges patterns in blender models?

Tags: modeling

Specifically, I want to get the details (like the black ridge-sort of things) and the blue glowing line along with other shapes (you may have to zoom in to view the details clearly in the image).

How can I modify my scene and/or model to obtain the dark shadows as in the reference images?

Also, can someone explain concisely how does the mean crease and edge split work? The grooves and ridges are still the most difficult thing for me. There's just too much detail and I don't know how to model it. I tried looking online for some tutorials, and the hardops plugin seems to be useful, but I'll have to learn it and I gotta model and texture the whole thing within 24 hours.

It would be great if someone posted a video explaining how to create the black surfaces (with details as given) or maybe provide a link for some tutorial that is easy to follow for a beginner.

Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload **and embed** images using the built in functionality on the site so that the images do not become unavailable later on.

Comment: @VRM Could only upload one. Is there a problem with Google Drive?

Comment: Yes, those files might get moved or deleted. Also, **images should be embedded** so that nobody has to click a link to view the image.

Comment: @VRM Will you help me now?

Comment: I think you should try and do this all in Blender really. You have two options, paint/bake the glowing or deal with emissive maps and materials.

Comment: @VRM Thanks. But I'm having a bit more difficulty with all the grooves and ridges that are black. As you might have guessed, I'm a beginner.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is going on the the reference image. I'd try to create a bump map in an image editing software.

Comment: @Dontwalk ...any tutorial to help me with that? Noob here :) And I know this is a tough thing to make for a beginner but I'm willing to do the hard work. Just need a photorealistic model.

Comment: I see that you can easily generate bump maps from images but there is none (I guess, it's an unusual model for images to be lying around) so I'll have to do it manually (?) and I don't knowhow to do that.

Comment: It is a unique model. As in many cases there might be different ways to accomplish it. I would UV Unwrap it and export the UV Map. Bring the map into a photo editing application and hand draw the "black ridge-sort of things" and use that as a bump map in Blender.